# Why does this Function (Which Pushes Objects to an Array) Crash p5.js?

Tags: javascript, performance, p5.js

I am building an evolution simulation app where if a certain organism has health above 75%, it reproduces, then the health is subtracted by half. To do this, I create a new instance of the class the object belongs to then push said object to the array where the other organisms are stored. This crashes p5.js for a reason I am not aware of.

I have tried to lessen the number of organisms (3) and write it as a function of the class.

```
var organisms = []; // array where organisms instances go

function reproduce(){
  for (let i = 0; i < organisms.length; i++){
     if(organisms[i].life > 0.75){
        // create a genetically similar size
        let size = organisms[i].size + (random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1 * random() * 2);   
        // declare instance
        let org = new Organism(width, height, size)
        organisms.push(org);
        // prevent infinite reproduction
        organisms[i].life -= 0.5;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect this to just create new class instances, but it crashes p5.js.

Comment: You're altering an array while iterating over it; that's always a bad idea. Create a new array first, then append it to `organisms` after the loop is done. (if the new organism always has a `.life > 0.75`, this will create an infinite loop)

Comment: @ChrisG Ok, would `let arr = organisms;` at the beginning of the function then  `organisms = arr;` at the end work? Also does the `organisms[i].life -= 0.5;` not deal with the infinite loop problem?

Comment: No, `let arr = organisms;` doesn't create a copy of the array. What you can do however is store the length of the array in a variable and use that in your loop condition. That way the loop will finish at the last original element. As for `.life`, what is the initial value of a newly created organism?

Comment: @ChrisG Each organism begins with `this.life = 1` and it decrements by 0.01 every frame `this.life -= 0.01`

Comment: `i < organisms.length` is checked before each iteration; since you keep adding elements that all have `.life > 0.75` and thus create new elements, the loop never ends. Anyway, like I said, store the length in a variable before going into the loop and use that variable as limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the array and create the new organisms and then after the loop add the array of newly created organisms to your original array.

Here is a runnable snippet that creates a minimal example. The `random` method call from the question has been replaced with a call to `Math.random()` and `width` and `height` have been declared to eliminate the need for p5.js.

```js
    var organisms = []; // array where organisms instances go
    var width = 100;
 var height = 100;
 
 function Organism(w, h, s){
 this.width = w;
 this.height = h;
 this.size = s;
 this.life = .76;
 }
 organisms.push(new Organism(1,1,1));
    console.log("Organisms length before reproduce: " + organisms.length);
 reproduce();
    console.log("Oganisms length after reproduce:  "+organisms.length);

    function reproduce(){
      var organismsToAdd = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < organisms.length; i++){
         if(organisms[i].life > 0.75){
            // create a genetically similar size
            let size = organisms[i].size + (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1 * Math.random() * 2);   
            // declare instance
            let org = new Organism(width, height, size)
            organismsToAdd.push(org);
            // prevent infinite reproduction
            organisms[i].life -= 0.5;
            }
        }
      //organisms = organisms.concat(organismsToAdd);
      // or
   organisms.push.apply(organisms, organismsToAdd)
    }
```

Here is a runnable snippet with p5.js

```js
      var organisms = []; // array where organisms instances go

function setup(){
  createCanvas(100,100);
   organisms.push(new Organism(1,1,1));
  noLoop();
  }
  
  function draw(){
   console.log("Organisms length before reproduce: " + organisms.length);
   reproduce();
    console.log("Organisms length after reproduce: " + organisms.length);
  }
    function reproduce(){
      var organismsToAdd = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < organisms.length; i++){
         if(organisms[i].life > 0.75){
            // create a genetically similar size
            let size = organisms[i].size + (random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1 * random() * 2);   
            // declare instance
            let org = new Organism(width, height, size)
            organismsToAdd.push(org);
            // prevent infinite reproduction
            organisms[i].life -= 0.5;
            }
        }
  //    organisms = organisms.concat(organismsToAdd);
   organisms.push.apply(organisms, organismsToAdd)
    }
   
 function Organism(w, h, s){
   this.width = w;
   this.height = h;
   this.size = s;
   this.life = .76;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't think why this would crash your browser. Try to isolate the code that is causing the issue. Let me turn my answer into a runnable snippet. Take the code in the runnable snippet and add your code to it until you start having the issue again..

Comment: There was an error with the looping this works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've created a loop condition which may never end.

```
for (let i = 0; i < organisms.length; i++){
```

On the first iteration, let's say organisms has 5 elements. If the `if` condition on the next line is met, you will add another element to your `organisms` array. The next iteration will alter the next element in `organisms`, but since your array grows by one each time, you will never reach the end of the array!

Comment: True, but an answer is supposed to solve the problem :)